# Hadoop mapreduce / hive affected by internet connection?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, cloud

I have been trying to execute a complex query using hive, but I have not been successful.

The query is complex-ish and requires about 12 jobs. I'm executing it on a <strike>single node</strike> pseudo-execution hadoop configuration.

The query is always stuck on the very first job. It has not been able to go past 0%. However for some reason today, it managed to get to 55% before dropping back down to 0%. This doesn't make sense to me but it happens.

Upon looking at the log files, I found this line in the yarn resource manager's log file:

> Application attempt appattempt_1424491698765_0006_000001 doesn't exist in ApplicationMasterService cache.

The execution stops straight after that and never bounced back.

Upon looking up this error on google, this seems to happen when one manually kills a mapreduce job. However, I didn't even try to kill it.
See: [Kill YARN Job doesn't kill the container](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SAMZA-498)

When I look at the time when the error was reported, the only anomaly in the system I can find was that the internet connection was down at that time - I have a really bad internet service at home. My understanding of hadoop is that if it's just a <strike>single node</strike> pseudo-execution configuration, it shouldn't need internet connection to execute a job?

Having said that all my past attempts on executing the query may have failed due to the fact the internet connection has been unstable? That's the only common denominator between all those failures.

Moreover, that's pretty much the only error I've been seeing when I went through the log of all the failed attempts for executing this same query.

UPDATE:
I found another common anomaly. The mapreduce always stop at whatever % it's currently on and goes back to 0% when the cummulative CPU time exceed 5000 sec. Does this make sense to anyone?

Comment: Hadoop doesn't need Internet access if you're not specifically telling it to access the Internet.

Comment: `I'm executing it on a single node hadoop configuration.` why would you do that with such a large job?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut, oh wait no..i just realised mine is a pseudo-execution mode. My bad..

Comment: It will be better if you post an answer to your question if you have resolved it and accept it :)